# rotate tables to rows without using pivot tables in oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have tried to rotate adf tables to rows using pivot table and iterator, but its not working. If using iterator with panel tabs its working. I need to rotate the table without panel tab. Is there any other methods to rotate the adf table to rows without using the panel tab and pivot table?

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried and it is not working?

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://adfspecialists.blogspot.in/2013/02/using-afiterator-with-masterdetail.html